Is "spell me" not US idiom? Or perhaps archaic now?
We were looking at something:

wiping her brow You gotta spell me for awhile!

To me it clearly and obviously means "you take over for a while, so I can have a break".
However two colleagues – 20-30ish Americans – didn't really follow what was meant; everyone else (including non-native speakers, Brits, Yanks, young, old, etc) seemed to.
Could it be that, unknown to me, (a) this is much more British English, and/or indeed (b) it's now very old-fashioned?
(Indeed, my guess would have been that it's more American than Brit, but maybe that's completely wrong. Thinking about it, using the word as a noun, let's go over here for a spell, seems more Brit, but "spell me!" seems more can-do Yankee ... IDK.)
I've been trying to find some examples in film/TV where a character uses "spell me..." (perhaps particularly in sports or? maybe an action/war setting, someone spells someone else on lookout) but cannot.
As always there's no real corpus of spoken English, always a problem. You can instantly search all song lyrics, which is great, but this doesn't strike me as that sort of phrase.
Any ideas?

Aside: As a curiosity, this from a script set 25 years ago (ie, in late 1997 specifically) although written presently.

I think it's not a common phrase outside professions that involve people operating in shifts. But it's not archaic, just unfamiliar to many people.

I'll bet it's still in common use in the military, for example.

Oxford Languages calls it 'North American' (google 'spell definition', scroll down to No. 3).

K.B.: thanks, I did notice that; you know, it's so difficult to get a read on "what is archaic" and "what is regional".  (Hence, get expert opinions on ESC.) You know, I was brought up "ridiculously internationally" so I'm a bad judge; an example is I literally can never remember which side is "boot/trunk", "sidewalk/footpath" etc - !

@Barmar interesting; you know, at first I thought "surely that's in war movies all the time"; but thinking about it more, it seems like a kind of woozy, pansy-ass thing to say you know? ("Someone spell me on these nuclear laser beam controls!" sort of thing sounds a bit wrong, not what Arnie would say :) ). But IDK

@Fattie We say "trunk/elevator" on the right side, they say "boot/lift" on the wrong side. :)

I've always been familiar with this meaning in AmE. Googling today's news I see "He’s special. They ask a lot of him. Me coming in, I want to be able to spell him. He doesn’t have to guard the point guard the whole game or whatever it is he feels he needs to do, and give him even more bounce, more energy.” Said by Mike Conley, a basketball player.

@Barmar with footpath/sidewalk I literally had to come up with a mnemonic -> cowboy movies -> the footpaths/sidewalks? are made of boards -> "boardwalk" -> yankee.  I gave up on other such pairs!

@DjinTonic GREAT exemplar thank you so much!

I’m familiar with the term, and would also think of it as very American… but then I’m not a 20-something anymore, so that’s perhaps not so strange. It doesn’t feel archaic or obsolete to me as such, but it does have a distinctly ‘distant’ feel to me – that is, I’d never think to use it myself, and truth be told I’m not entirely sure I’ve ever heard anyone actually use it in real life. It feels to me like the kind of thing you’d hear from Hawkeye on M.A.S.H. or in sports jargon (where I’d be utterly lost anyway), more than from a normal person in normal conversation.

@JanusBahsJacquet good report, thanks.  It's funny you mention MASH, heh, yes that's a good example.

(In the US) I have heard "take a spell" to mean "take a break", but it definitely sounds very old and I'd never use it myself.

As always there's no real corpus of spoken English, always a problem. - See https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/ and also https://www.google.com/search?q="spell%20me%20for"&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2018,cd_max:2022&lr=lang_en

As a native British speaker in my mid 30s, who has also worked in shift-based jobs in the past, I can honestly say that I have never heard this phrase. So much so that I read the title literally, as in, spell out the letters of the word "me" and got confused :P It's an interesting one since "spot me" (to ask for a small amount of money on loan) is relatively common

This thread from 2015 claims "spell me" is primarily associated with some parts of the southern USA (but not Florida), but was also used in the UK. Also, this sense of "spell" is more common as a noun than as a verb. https://ww2talk.com/index.php?threads/use-of-term-spell-me.59740/

It occurs somewhat regularly in sports commentary.

@bradimus - you're meaning in the USA right ?

@PM2Ring fascinating discussion you link to TY.  That ties in to the notion that, in the UK, it's more northern than southern (which ties in to the "US South rather than Yankee" notion).

As a native Brit I've never heard this.

I believe I have heard this from AAVE speakers here in the USA. That would explain the Connely reference above. Its certainly not common in the general vernacular.

(I did not know the AAVE acronym TY) More fascinating info.  Since the US "South" is basically New Scotland + the French quarter, that sort of vaguely ties in to the "Northern British" issue mentioned a couple times

This isn't even a particularly common phrase in british english...

@T.E.D. In AAVE I'd expect it to mean "tell me how to spell" a word, not "take over for me".

It's concerning that a native speaker wouldn't be able to understand the meaning from context, even if they had literally never heard it before. It's definitely old-timey, but you hear people say 'sit a spell' or 'take a spell' occasionally.

@Barmar - Er...well, I grew up rather AAVE adjacent and had to learn to understand it at least, and haven't heard it used in that sense. "Spell" in AAVE is both a small amount of time (also in SAE), and as a verb the act of giving someone a small amount of time. Most often seen in phrases like "come sit a spell".

@T.E.D. I've never been close to AAVE. I was thinking of it as analogous to "learn me" == "teach me". "Sit a spell" is southern English, from which much AAVE is derived.

@Barmar - I think "learn me" is more Appaplachian (and perhaps even ultimately its ancestral Scottish English, since I see there's a song by that name in Brave?)

@T.E.D. Possibly. There's lots of overlap and transmission.

I am British, aged over 70, and I am familiar with this usage of 'spell', and I think of it as slightly old-fashioned, and maybe rather American. I have heard Australians say it.

@MichaelHarvey in the context of having someone relieving you of a shift? Of course we use things like "he had a spell with Industry X" or likewise, but someone asking you to "spell" them?

@roganjosh - that is exactly what I mean. The OED has it, quoting from 1595 to 1873 _1.1 trans. To take the place of (a person) at some work or labour; to relieve (another) by taking a turn at work. Now U.S. _ also b.1.b To relieve by an interval of rest; to rest (esp. a horse). Chiefly Austr. and _2.2 Naut. To take a turn or turns of work at (the pump, etc.). and _3.3 intr. a.3.a To replace one set of workers by another; to take turns. andb.3.b Austr. To take an interval of rest.

@roganjosh (I feel you may be overreacting - it's a commonplace that people born after say 1990 read or write p;oorly and have poor vocabulary.  (This is mentioned constantly on this site, as you'd expect, since the site is about English! So you'll be canceling a lot of people! :) ) I even went to pains to point out that is "just a fact", not a good or bad thing. It's as uninteresting and commonplace as pointing out that in popular music since the introduction of DAWs, musicianship has become comically bad.  Anyway I have surely deleted the comment that offended you, cheers.)

I wonder why someone wanted to close this question?  (I couldn't care less, I'm not a prosus shareholder, just curious!) {I don't think it lists "close vote reasons" ?}

@Fattie Just curious, why did you remove the "is" I added in my edit? The last sentence is missing a verb, that's why I added it.

cheers @wjandrea PS thanks for the edits!  "this from  ..." is perfectly correct, "this" referring to "this topic under discussion, this issue".  Using the "is" is also perfectly correct, of course.  (I guess it's "my post" and it should suffer "my writing" unless it's an actual typo, mistake, etc.)  Actually, I love the idea of editing posts "for style" - I would edit every single post to my writing style :)

I am an American of Generation X, and I can verify that my father, an American of the Baby Boom generation, used to ask if I wanted him to spell me whenever we were doing construction projects together.  (He would also say, sooner or later, many more colorful but less printable things.)

@Fattie I think I know what you mean, but it's too informal for the context and I think it's only used to point out hypocrisy, like "Did you hear? The mayor's complaining about crime. This from the guy who slashed the police budget." BTW, "PS" means "post-script", so you can't put it before the bulk of what you're saying.

@wjandrea Sorry to be disagreeable, it's not informal (rather, it is quaint, formal, pointed, somewhat old-fashioned and indeed "writerly"; Churchill used it often for example). (You mention or imply that you have only seen it used to "point out hypocrisy": any phrase in English can be used in a snarky or sarcastic manner  - particularly anything formalish, haughty, or writerly sounding such as the wording in question.) PS your explanation of PS would be useful for anyone under 50 who's reading :), TY rock on!

@DougWarren THANKS for that great report !!!  lol on the colorful variations

@Fattie Could you give an example?

@wjandrea i suggest asking a question about it!

@bradimus Yep, I read it in sports context occasionally: see https://www.mlbtraderumors.com/?s=spell

I'm an American in my 50s.  I don't recall every hearing this sense of spell as a verb.  I have heard spell as a noun:  "I need to sit for a spell."  To my ear, that usage sounds very old fashioned though it may have held on longer in the South and/or the Midwest.

@Fattie Yes, US sports. Especially basketball and American football where players are substituted regularly for brief rests.

I’ve never heard it before (American English here), but there it is in the OED:

spell verb3
1.a. transitive. To take the place of (a person) at some work or labour; to relieve (another) by taking a turn at work. Now U.S.
1595– Source: Oxford English Dictionary (login required)


Responding to "I've never heard it before...":  Weird.  I am a native speaker of American English, and the phrase "Can you spell me for a bit?" feels quite natural to me.  Maybe it is regional (my language is fairly pan-regional---I picked up a lot of Midwesternisms while living in Iowa, but also get a lot of my language from SoCal, the Southwest, and New Jersey (other places I lived while growing up)?  or a generational thing (I'm in my mid 40s)?

According to Google Ngrams Viewer, it not only continues to have currency in American English writing, but has become quite a bit more common there since the turn of the millennium. (Caveat: this query will also pick up some ditransitive uses of "spell", like "spell me your name, please", but, as Sven Yargs points out in a comment, virtually all of the matches that come up if you run "Search in Google Books" with the buttons at the bottom of that page are in the sense under discussion.)
To be honest though, as a younger American living in a city in the Midwest, I have only encountered the phrase in high-school literature, never spoken.  To my ear it sounds old-timey, more associated with an era in which manual labor was more common.  It makes me think of sailing, or farming, or the American South, and does not feel like a phrase I would ever expect to encounter in my own dialect.
Comparing the comments left on the question, I suspect that familiarity with the phrase, although American English, depends a lot on class and geographic region—and maybe also how much literature one reads.  It's certainly believable to me that your colleagues, if they grew up in an environment similar to mine, would have never encountered it before.

If you sharpen the phrase to read as "to spell me," you get an Ngram graph that shoots upward over the period from 1996 to 2017. And if you click the links beneath the graph for examples from recent time periods, you'll see that many are from U.S. publications and most are using "to spell me" in the idiomatic sense that the poster asks about. This strongly suggests that "to spell me" is not dropping out of idiomatic English in the U.S.

@SvenYargs Yep. A tiny correction: your link is for the entire English corpus, not that it affects your conclusions when the American English subcorpus also shows the same trends and types of search results.

@SvenYargs that is KEY information.

@MichaelHarvey right, I agree !

We use it in Scotland and the North of England meaning a rest; it can be applied as a transitive verb. My gran always uses it as a noun ("I'm going to have a spell") meaning she's going for a lie down.
Personally I don't often hear it used as a verb, but that said I've never worked shift-work or on a sports team here so would never have cause to use it; it makes sense that someone substituting you would be "spelling you": giving you a rest.
The Collins, based on the COBUILD corpus, shows its continued use in the UK in both forms:

spell
in British English
...
3.  Scottish, Australian and New Zealand
a period or interval of rest
...
4. (transitive)
to take over from (a person) for an interval of time; relieve temporarily
...
Old English spelian to take the place of, of obscure origin

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spell#spell__4
As is often the case with Scots Language, it has its roots in Old English (at least the noun form) but apparently fell out of use in other parts in the UK. Following the Highland Clearances, it makes sense that our compatriots now resident in the US would have passed down the word, as appears to have been the case with our Antipodean brethren.

Fascinating!  I originate from Scotland (although for better or worse I had a very mixed situation over the years) so that could well be why it is perhaps apparently more natural to me than others. Just as you say, yanks, particularly Southern yanks, are basically Scots. So this report suggests to me it is not so much the case that it is "more US English these days".  I feel the end result may be "it's becoming a little more obscure, equally in both regions ..."

This may be why, for me, it's not uncommon at all. My mother comes from South Carolina which had some Scottish immigrants. My mother also spoke of having a mix of heritage including Scottish. Adding to other comments on other answers, my mother's family also did a lot of shift work in textile factories.

@Fattie indeed, you don't hear of it so much nowadays in the UK; hence the example of my grandma. That said, former colonies are often more traditional in their use of language (even French and Dutch colonies). For instance, what's seen as a US tendency of using "-ize" (Latin, Greek) instead of "-ise" (French) is actually the earlier English form practised in the UK, having changed in the late 19th Century. But oddly enough, we're seeing a modern resurgence of "-ize" owing to the US's cultural influence in media. We're being handing back our old words!

gotchya @Rab (I have not lived in or spent much time in the UK for a few yrs). Fascinating analysis

@DaveD - that's amazing!!!!  PS Roll Tide :)
